# How to display the results of a request in a modal window

Tags: php, sql, database, modal-dialog

I use a modal window to display the results of a database search. The problem is that no results are displayed, and this because of the modal window, I do not know how to use it. The program never executes the statement:

```
if (isset ($ _ POST ['button']))
```

How to do ?

Comment: try to print out to the DIV to see if the PHP side is working. After you'll get the results you will play with modal window

Comment: it works without modal

Comment: so what kind of modal window are you using? Is it standard modal or some  framework?

Comment: it is a bootstrap modal